# how do i eliminate a particular value when an id has more than one value in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query which returns more than one row for few ID's with different values. In such a case i need to eliminate the ID's with certain data.

**Example**

[image]

I need to elimate A1 for all those ID's which has more than one name and else if it has only  one value A1 then i should be able to display it.

**Result Should look like:**

```
ID   Name  Value
1     A1     AA    
1     B1     AB
2     C1     CC
3     A1     AA
4     A1     AA
4     E1     AD
4     B1     AB
```

[image]

Please a solution for this

Comment: What is the query you are currently using?  You need to eliminate the id row that contains a certain name and value pair, or with a certain name or value?

Comment: i am trying to write a case statement with a count but its not  giving me the desired result. I need to display the entire row if the id has only one result set else i need to eliminate the value A1 for that id and display the other random value for the same ID.

Comment: Please provide the table structure & what you are attempting to produce. I suspect that the problem is more in the structure than the subsequent query you are attempting on that structure.
Additionally, if the structure is decent there may be more effective ways to do this than a case.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably very ugly, but at least gets the job done:

```
select id, name, value from (
  select f.*, c.count 
  from <TABLE> f, (select *, count(*) as 'count' from <TABLE> group by id) c 
  where f.id = c.id
  ) c 
where (name = 'A1' and count = 1) or name != 'A1' 
group by id
```

you will get the 'first' row for remaining (not random) for `id = 4`